# How to get Postfix to send mail from multiple domains?

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I recently installed Webmin, Postfix, and Dovecot on a fresh Debian Wheezy system. Everything is working fine, except I'd like to know how I can configure Postfix to not only receive but also send mail from multiple domains.

I have one domain (the default) that sends and receives mail just fine. I have a system user named "joey", and mapped to him is `joey@domain1.com`. I have another user named "joey.domain2" who has `joey@domain2.com` mapped to him. I have no problems with receiving mail (I do most through Webmin) - receiving mail addressed to `joey@domain2.com` will have it delivered to joey.domain2's mailbox just fine. However, when I reply to it, the address appears to the receiver (I test stuff on Gmail) as `joey.domain2@domain1.com`.

How do I configure postfix so that I can send mail through other addresses rather than the default?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>**Bot**: convert [self-answered-post-in-question-section](https://serverfault.com/posts/574293/revisions) to CW</sub>

[Canonical mapping](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#canonical) fixed this problem for me.

Putting this line

```
joey.domain2@domain1.com    joey@domain2.com
```

in `/etc/postfix/canonical` allowed me to send mail from Domain 2. I set Webmin to read `hash:/etc/postfix/canonical` as all three canonical normal/send/receive mapping files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check

```
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#append_dot_mydomain 
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#append_at_myorigin.
```

If you have a multiple domains I would suggest to use virtual domains with postfixadmin

Answer (score 0):

You  may use generic to rewrite adresses in outgoing emails from OS accounts.
[ It is equivalent of sendmail's genericstable ]

http://www.postfix.org/generic.5.html